# Embed FLV video on a web page

Tags: video, streaming, flash, flv

What is the way to embed a FLV video on a web page

- Are there available SWF ready to use and easy to customise that would allow a streaming of the FLV from our site to the client browser?
- In this case what would be the wrapping code to run and setup that SWF?

Any other solution that would work for most people can be interesting.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I recommend JWPlayer. It's not F/LOSS, but free for personal use and commercial license is quite cheap.

Comment: Thanks. With a FLV, there is no other alternative than a player seemingly?

Comment: No, you need Flash to play FLV (Flash Video)